# Panel item listener of click event only fires once

Tags: extjs

the select listener is only firing once.Than returns and appended property of
firing: false
on the second click. How can I prevent this from happening?

here is an example: http://supraliminalsolutions.com/pages/example-apps/campusBuildings/

```
        xtype: 'combo',
        store: ds,
        displayField: 'title',
        typeAhead: false,
        hideLabel: true,
        hideTrigger:true,
        anchor: '100%',
        minChars: 1,
        listConfig: {
            loadingText: 'Searching...',
            emptyText: 'No matching buildings found.',

            // Custom rendering template for each item
            getInnerTpl: function() {
                return '<div class="search-item">{name}</div>';
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10,

        // override default onSelect to do redirect
        listeners: {
            'select': function(combo, selection) {
                console.log('you there?');
                var building = selection[0];
                if (building) {

                    retrieveBuildingInfo(Ext.String.format(env_url + 'building.php?id={0}', building.get('id')));
                }
            },
                    'expand': function() {
                        Ext.Msg.alert("test","do you see me");// this alert never show, when the combo expanded
                        console.log(this.events.select);
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply reset the form after the event handling logic executes likeso:

```
            'select': function(combo, selection) {
                console.log('you there?');
                var building = selection[0];
                if (building) {

                    retrieveBuildingInfo(Ext.String.format(env_url + 'building.php?id={0}', building.get('id')));
                }
                this.reset();
            },
```

I am not sure if it is the best way to do it but it works

Comment: I've got the same issue with a combo in a toolbar. Calling `this.reset()` keeps the select listener, but the combobox shows an empty value...